# Iterate over 2 list with different element

Tags: python, iteration, python-itertools

All the guru here, I was wondering if there's any simple or clear syntax to perform the following itertools function:
Instead taking 1 element from each list, I would like to take 1 element from list_A and 2 elements from list_B.

The output seem very messy with all the bracket, so wondering if there's any simplest way of doing that.

Appreciate all the helps.

```
list_A = [1,2,3]
list_B = ['a','b','c']
list_AB = [itertools.combinations(list_A,1), itertools.combinations(list_B,2)]
result = [element for element in itertools.product(*list_AB)]
```

it shows:

```
[((1,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((1,), ('a', 'c')),
 ((1,), ('b', 'c')),
 ((2,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((2,), ('a', 'c')),
 ((2,), ('b', 'c')),
 ((3,), ('a', 'b')),
 ((3,), ('a', 'c')),
 ((3,), ('b', 'c'))]
```

expected:

```
[(1,'a','b'),
 (1,'a','c'),
 (1,'b','c'),
 #......,
 (3,'b',c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
list_A = [1,2,3]
list_B = ['a','b','c']

[x+y for x in itertools.combinations(list_A,1) for y in itertools.combinations(list_B,2)]

#output
[(1, 'a', 'b'),
 (1, 'a', 'c'),
 (1, 'b', 'c'),
 (2, 'a', 'b'),
 (2, 'a', 'c'),
 (2, 'b', 'c'),
 (3, 'a', 'b'),
 (3, 'a', 'c'),
 (3, 'b', 'c')]
```

**Explanation**:

Instead of using `itertools.product` I am using a nested for loop in list comprehension

```
list(itertools.combinations(list_A,1))
#[(1,), (2,), (3,)]

list(itertools.combinations(list_B,2))
#[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
list_A = [1,2,3]
list_B = ['a','b','c']
result = [(a, *b) for a,b in itertools.product(list_A,
                                               itertools.combinations(list_B, 2)
                                               )]
```

Or for a generic approach with an arbitrary number of lists (full itertools solution, you can replace [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with list comprehensions if you want):

```
from itertools import combinations, product, chain

lists = [list_A, list_B]
repeats = [1, 2]

result = [tuple(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in
          product(*map(combinations, lists, repeats))]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a', 'b'),
 (1, 'a', 'c'),
 (1, 'b', 'c'),
 (2, 'a', 'b'),
 (2, 'a', 'c'),
 (2, 'b', 'c'),
 (3, 'a', 'b'),
 (3, 'a', 'c'),
 (3, 'b', 'c')]
```

Comment: Your `(combinations(l, r) for l, r in zip(lists, repeats))` could be `map(combinations, lists, repeats)`.